# python function showing error, matrix, vectors, reading csv file

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I have this code now:

```
def computeFinalGrades(grades):

# loading and reading the file
gradesCSV=pd.read_csv(grades)
print(gradesCSV)

# creating matrix only with the grades
matrixGrades=np.array(gradesCSV.iloc[0:8,2:])
print(matrixGrades)

# creating empty array
result_vector=[]

for array in matrixGrades:
    if -3 not in array: 
        array = array[~np.isnan(array)] # removing any NaN values
        if len(array) == 1:
            mean_result = array[0]
        else:
            min_value = min(array)
            mean_result = (sum(array)-min(array))/(len(array)-1)
            print(mean_result)
    else: #-3 is in the list
        mean_result = -3
    result_vector.append(mean_result)
print(result_vector)
 
gradesFinal=np.array(result_vector)        

return gradesFinal

computeFinalGrades('test.csv')
```

And in this line: mean_result = (sum(array)-min(array))/(len(array)-1) it should return a rounded number which is rounded with another function I have and import.

It keeps giving me an error, so have can I use my round-function? It works fine in another file with both float-number and a vector

Comment: What should be min(matrix) in this case?

Comment: The lowest value in the row of the matrix

Comment: The idea is that it should work row-wise and then return a vector

Comment: Ok, but what should be min(matrix) in the matrix you posted? Please be more specific. I mean, what is matrix.remove(min(matrix)) supposed to do? Kindly give an example.

Comment: matrix.remove(min(matrix)) should remove the lowest value in the row. So if the row has 2 values (or more), the number with the lowest  value  should be deleted and then the mean of the remaining numbers should be computed

Comment: ok, but which row, because in your code you are doing all cases with the entire matrix, and if it is with all the rows of the matrix, you have to use a for loop to iterate over the rows, if you're not already doing it and you forgot to put it.

Comment: No I have no loop and Im honestly just so lost. I am doing it on the entire matrix, but it should be row-wise and I just dont know how

Comment: Ok, no worries, I just taught you forgot to post a for loop tha overate over the rows. To do that iteration row-wise, see @ItaiBenAmram's answer, that would be a way to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an optional solution (a bit messy but simple (brute iterative force!) )

EDIT: after talking with the author of the question, i'm posting the full code that helped him solve the question.

```
import numpy as np

result_vector = []
full_array = np.array(a) # I don't think I understand what a is here
for array in matrixGrades:
    if -3 not in array:
        array = array[~np.isnan(array)]
        if len(array) == 1:
            grade = roundedGrade(array[0])
        else:
            grade = math.floor((sum(array)-min(array))/(len(array)-1))
            grade = roundGrade(grade)
    else: #-3 is in the list
        grade = -3
    result_vector.append(grade)
print(result_vector)


def roundGrade(grades):
       
    # possible grades
    Grade=np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])
    
    for i in range(len(grades)):
        index=(np.abs(Grade-grades[i])).argmin()
        gradeRounded = Grade[index]
        
    return gradeRounded
```

you can of course turn the list into a vector using `np.array` ...

Comment: Hi! I tried with your code, and I still have some errors, but I cant post it here because I have limitation on characters. Is it possible you can help in a "chat room" ?

Comment: I dont know how to create a chatroom, do you know how to?

Comment: Oh its because I dont have enough reputation yet

Comment: I will try here: so I have another function that round the values to a correct one and it should be implemented in this: `mean_result = (sum(array)-min(array))/(len(array)-1)` somehow. The function takes a value and outputs another value. But when I try this: `mean_result = roundfunction((sum(array)-min(array))/(len(array)-1))` it says  TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Comment: well that's because it's looking for a list, and mean_result gives you a number, if you have a function that already calculates the num then do the following:  `mean_result = roundfunction(array)`

Comment: I have now: 

`result_vector=[]

    for array in matrixGrades:
        if -3 not in array: 
            array = array[~np.isnan(array)] #removing any NaN values
            if len(array) == 1:
                mean_result = array[0]
            else:
                min_value = min(array)
                mean_result = (sum(array)-min(array))/(len(array)-1)
                print(mean_result)
        else: #-3 is in the list
            mean_result = -3
        result_vector.append(mean_result)`

Comment: followed by: `print(result_vector)
     
    gradesFinal=np.array(result_vector)        
    
    return gradesFinal

computeFinalGrades('test.csv')`

Comment: And it doesn't work when I type `mean_result = roundfunction(array)`

Comment: The roundfunction can take a vector and number as input
`def roundGrade(grades):
       
    # En vektor med de karakter som man kan få
    Grade=np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])
    
    # Nulvektor med antal af studerende 
    S=np.size(grades)
    gradesRounded=np.zeros(S)
    
    for i in range(len(grades)):
        index=(np.abs(Grade-grades[i])).argmin()
        #print(index)
        gradesRounded[i]=Grade[index]
        
    return gradesRounded`

Comment: hmmm kind of difficult to understand, comment section isn't the best place to do this- how about you edit your question with all the relevant new info and I'll try to help :)

Comment: Good idea!! Ill try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216326/discussion-between-pineapples-and-itai-ben-amram).

Comment: I think we have a chatroom https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216326/discussion-between-pineapples-and-itai-ben-amram